# How to click on the Extension icon using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79R7B.png)

How can we resolve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click on a Chrome extension button with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51524109/how-to-click-on-a-chrome-extension-button-with-selenium)

Comment: Maybe [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524957/20443541) helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using Sikulix to click on the extension as it works on the GUI rather than Element location.
Pattern iconLight = new Pattern("C:\Users\HemantAttri\Pictures\e");
Pattern iconDark = new Pattern("C:\Users\HemantAttri\Pictures\ei");

```
    // Create a screen region to search for the icon
    

    // Search for the icon and click on it
    Match icon = null;
    if (screen.exists(iconLight) != null) {
        // Use the light theme icon
        icon = screen.exists(iconLight);
    } else if (screen.exists(iconDark) != null) {
        // Use the dark theme icon
        icon = screen.exists(iconDark);
    }
    if (icon != null) {
        icon.click();
    } else {
        System.out.println("icon was not found"); 
        
    }
```