# what is the purpose of chrome-extension inject.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension

Hello I have a react project which is working full and functional but when I look into network form console I find an unexpected script called

> chrome-extension://gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg/js/inject.js

which is not associated with my project. Is that a virus or an extension ??

In my

> chrome://extensions/

there is nothing called inject. Can anyone tell me what is this? This script loading for all site in my browser. Is my browser compromised?? I am walking totally in dark.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The string `gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg` is the [Chrome extension ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946325/chrome-extension-id-how-to-find-it). You can search this ID in the Chrome Web Store to find that it is [Wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wappalyzer/gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg).

The inject.js file is not inherently malicious because of its name. To look at the javascript yourself, you can look at the contents of js/inject.js by finding the
`gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg` folder in your [Chrome Extension directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions).

Answer (score 1):

`gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg` is the ID of the `Wappalyzer - Technology profiler` extension. Remove it if you want the call to go away

Answer (score 1):

The extention id `gppongmhjkpfnbhagpmjfkannfbllamg` Is `Wappalyzer - Technology profiler`

It uses the `inject.js` to discover what technologies the page has and send it back to the extension